# Count number of purchases a user has done on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I have a pandas data-frame with both orders and simple access to a book file, I want to get a separate data-frame where I can see which orders make each user and discard the accesses.

This is an example of the format of my data-frame:

```
    number  type   username   product   order_code  order_datetime    model    price
0     1     order   alicia7    130365       ...        ...            ebook     5.99
1     1     order   alicia7    130365       ...        ...            ebook     5.99
2     4    access   7762hc      65487       ...        ...           printed   15.45
3     3    access   kylemm      45878       ...        ...            ebook     7.99
4     1     order   john5       32054       ...        ...           printed   18.99
```

Number just indicates the number of times a user accessed a book file. So, the result I'm trying to achieve is that, a new data frame where I have each order a user made and it would be even better if I can just group the purchases a user made of the same book, like, add a new column with the total amount of the same book that user bought. Something like this:

```
     type   username   product   count  
0   order   alicia7    130365      2       
4   order   john5       32054      1
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter values by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then count by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
print (df[df['type'].eq('order')])
   number   type username  product    model  price
0       1  order  alicia7   130365    ebook   5.99
1       1  order  alicia7   130365    ebook   5.99
4       1  order    john5    32054  printed  18.99

df1 = df[df['type'].eq('order')].groupby(['type','username','product']).size().reset_index(name='count')
```

Or filter by [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df1 = df.query('type=="order"').groupby(['type','username','product']).size().reset_index(name='count')

print (df1)
    type username  product  count
0  order  alicia7   130365      2
1  order    john5    32054      1
```

For all possible combinations without filter use:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['type','username','product']).size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df2)
     type username  product  count
0  access   7762hc    65487      1
1  access   kylemm    45878      1
2   order  alicia7   130365      2
3   order    john5    32054      1
```

Comment: I've tried both options but I'm getting an empty data frame

Comment: @SarahKerrigan - it means `order` values are no match, if check `print (df['type'].tolist())` there are not spme spaces like `' order'` ?

Comment: yes, sorry, I had some problems with exactly that hahaha thank you so much

Comment: I've been thinking... what if I wanted to have the user, the books he bought and the number of copies? Like: alicia7  [65487, 45878] [2, 1] where the first pair of numbers would be the product ID and the second the amount of each product, is this a thing?

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new with pandas and I'm trying to get myself into it

Comment: @SarahKerrigan - Do you need `df1.groupby(['username')['product','count'].agg(list).reset_index()` ?

Comment: That seems good, unique users with lists of items and count of products, I think I can try and work with that. Thank you so much!! You are good

Answer (score 0):

If I got you correctly, your code should look something like this:

```
df_gb = df.groupby(['type','username','product'],as_index=False).agg({'model':'count'}).rename(columns ={'model':'count'})
orders_filtered_df = df_gb[df_gb.type=='order']
```